# Characterization of Projective Objects

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

In which categories is an object $P$ projective if and only if every short exact sequence ending with it splits?
$$0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow P \longrightarrow 0$$

Comment: What do you consider a short exact sequence if the category is not abelian?

Comment: First of all, obviously, it has to be a category in which short exact sequences make sense. There are well-known definitions for abelian categories, but once you leave that world it becomes more subtle. Similarly, the notion of projective also becomes more subtle once you leave the world of abelian categories.

Comment: I was hoping for some nice statements about exact, additive, and semi-abelian categories.

Comment: It's already false for semi-abelian categories, unless you use the correct asymmetric notion of split short exact sequence.